# A new MVC view, 404's every time, Even with the proper controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013

I've just started a new MVC project. I've added 2 views successfully. I always add the view and update the home controller to route the new view... All was well until I added a new view and did the usual but that view is inaccessible no matter what I try. Debug mode: 404's. Publishing in release mode to IIS: 404's. It's the last ActionResult in my controller: StaleTickets.  All of the other endpoints in the Home Controller map successfully and I can visit them pre and post-publish. Any ideas? Appreciated.

**HomeController:**

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Title = "Dashboard";

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Calendar()
    {
        ViewBag.Title = "Calendar";

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Criticals()
    {
        ViewBag.Title = "Critical Tickets";

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult StaleTickets()
    {
        ViewBag.Title = "Stale Tickets";

        return View();
    }
```

**StaleTickets.cshtml**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "StaleTickets";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h1>Hello, World!</h1>
```

**RouteConfig (default)**

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");


        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

**Document Structure**

[image: Document Structure]

Comment: check the properties pane for the .cshtml file, make sure the Build Action is set to "Content". This can happen sometimes depending on how you created the file in the first place.

Comment: Try deleting that view and going back and adding it. From what you have posted it looks like it should work. Probably a weird property or something like @DLeh said. Make sure you do the right click on folder then add , view.

Comment: I will try both of your suggestions, thanks.

Comment: What's the URL you're browsing to?

Comment: @Will, I was browsing to /home/staletickets

Comment: Are you *suuuuure*?  I'd imagine debugging "saletickets" for a half hour before screaming in pain.

Comment: @DLeh and DROP TABLE users, It was a matter of deleting and re-creating the view, as per your suggestions. super weird. I'll close this out now. thanks a bunch.

Comment: @will I've tried ever possible combination of upper and lower cases. Screamed in pain until I deleted/recreated the view.

Comment: @JustinVanBibber glad you got it figured out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the comments above, I deleted/recreated the view in Visual Studio and it fixed the issue. I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and tried the above. It was only then that I realised I had misspelled my controller! Sometimes the simplest/silliest things can go unnoticed...

Answer (score 0):

My issue, which is another simple/silly error, was that I copied from another controller, so my namespace was incorrect.